# connecting localhost fastapi to react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, localhost, fastapi

I am trying to develop a react app that connects to a python fastapi server. I am developing the frontend and the backend both on my local computer. When I try to use the fetch API to get data from my python server, I get a bunch of errors stating CORS permissions denied and Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch. I have added "proxy": "HTTP://localhost:3000" to my package.json file and am still receiving the same error. How do I resolve this?
My backend is on port 80 and my frontend is on port 3000.
If there is any more information I could provide to make this post more clear please let me know.
I am relatively new to dealing with APIS and JS

[image: error messages]

This is my backend script

```
import math
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware


myApp = FastAPI()
userInput = 0

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "localhost:3000"
]


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins = origins,
    allow_credentials = True,
    allow_methods = ["*"],
    allow_headers = ["*"]
)


@myApp.get("/")
def default():
    return "enter a number after a slash in the URL"


@myApp.get("/is-prime")
def is_prime():
    prime = True
    sqrt = int(math.sqrt(userInput))
    for i in range(2, sqrt + 1):
        if userInput % i == 0:
            prime = False
            break

    return {"prime": prime}
```

This is my frontend script

```js
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            input: 0,
            prime: true,
            testList: []
        }

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("content is being loaded")
        fetch("http://localhost:80")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    prime: json["prime"],
                })
                console.log("content is loaded")
                console.log("testList is " + String(this.state.testList))
            });
        
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h2>Welcome to the prime finder App.</h2>
                    <p>Enter a Number below</p>
                    <form>
                        <input type="number"></input>
                        <button> Is it prime? </button>
                    </form>
                    <p>{this.state.prime ? "Yes its prime!" : "No its not prime"}</p>
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

First try to allow all origins, when it works fine u can try to restrict